# Colon after colon syntax while calling a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I came across a syntax somewhere on the web recently and couldn't grasp its meaning.

What I understand is that when we write `props: Object` inside the brackets, it means we're assigning a default value to props as Object. But what does the 2nd colon signify? It looks like a key-value pair but is confusing me still.

Tried searching on the web but wasn't able to search due to lack of terminology. Any ideas what this means?

```js
someFn(props: Object): Object {
  return someOtherFn(props);
}
```

Comment: You are probably seeing [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html)

Comment: That's TypeScript (or maybe something else), not JavaScript.

Comment: This is TypeScript or Flow syntax, is not the JavaScript default values syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are type annotations. They are not standard javascript. They are added when using tools that layer static typing onto javascript. The two most popular flavors are [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) and [Flow](https://flow.org/).

When you write code that uses this syntax you will *transpile* your source code into code that is syntactically valid for execution by running one of the above mentioned tools on your code. When you do, it will tell you if your usage of the types is correct, raise warnings that are helpful in development, and then strip all this out so it can actually be run.